# SetBasePath not present in ConfigurationBuilder under .NET Core 5

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, .net-5

According to the docs for .NET Core 5, there's a method [SetBasePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileconfigurationextensions.setbasepath?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) and it's widely used in a bunch of blogs ([example 1](https://www.zoneofdevelopment.com/2020/02/19/c-how-to-add-and-read-an-appsetting-json-file-in-a-console-application/), [example 2](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/csharp/appsettings+in+console+application+c%23), [example 3](https://dev.to/masanori_msl/net-core-play-with-console-app-268n) etc.). There's no notion of it being a weird gotcha or such. However, when I try the syntax below, it's marked red and claimed not to be there.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
  IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
  builder.SetBasePath(path);
}
```

I'm not sure why this happens not what to do about it.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a vanilla console application in .NET Core 5 in C#.
2. Paste in the code in *Program.cs* replacing the file's contents.
3. Try to compile or execute.

The error received is like this.

> Error CS1061
> 'ConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'SetBasePath' and no accessible extension method 'SetBasePath' accepting a first argument of type 'ConfigurationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

As far i can understand, I have all the prerequisites in place.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Remember that multiple types can contribute methods to a single type through [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).  And so `SetBasePath` was never a method on the `IConfigurationBuilder` interface.

And multiple Assemblies can contribute types to the same namespace, and the docs say the type that defines the `SetBasePath` extension method is in:

> FileConfigurationExtensions Class Definition Namespace:
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration Assembly:
> **Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll**

[FileConfigurationExtensions Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileconfigurationextensions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Which you can easilly verify is not present in your dependencies.  So you're missing a NuGet package.  Turns out this one is easy to find: [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions/)

Comment: Seems to be the precise issue. What puzzles me is that I haven't found this asked previously. It seems that there ought to be some other poor schmuck before me doing precisely that and not thinking about installing additional packages. Well, I guess I'm the original schmuck for this issue.

Comment: wow, appreciated what they've done breaking things down into smaller nuget packages, however, discoverable has been penalised here. i've had to look for a few more packages to get the some ported code working with .NET 6. 
easy way to find them all: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json package for an *.json file